# How to install Windows XP to the disk S

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, installation

I want to install Windows XP, but I want some kind of technique to create partition with installed Windows assign letter 'S', not letter 'C'. I think is possible, because if I turn my multi card reader before install, Windows assigned letter 'H'.

But I want letter 'S'. :-)

Comment: If there are no cards plugged in then the installer should still make the default location `C:`... Can you temporarily unplug or disable the card reader so that you can install Windows to its default `C:` and then, upon completion, re-enable/connect the reader back and it'll automatically work out new driver letters?

Comment: But I want letter S, not letter C.

Comment: Right, so you definitely want to assign "`S:`" as your system drive letter.

Comment: Yes, yes, yes...

Comment: During the Windows XP installer, you'll need to create a partition before you install. You can then mark the partition as active and assign it a drive letter - you can then choose this partition to install to.

Comment: I dont see this option during Windows XP install, only Create partition and/or install system.

Comment: OK, when you do "Create partition" what partition letter does it create to start with?

Comment: System automatically assign letter C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a program hait 'WinNTSetup' that allows you to set the letter of the install drive.  You need to install Windows NT (2000 or better), but you can have the first drive on S:   It works under Windows PE if i recall correctly.

If you don't have a c: drive, that letter gets used by usb sticks and cdroms.  There are programs that allow you to tell the system to use different letters for USB drives.  Look on Uwe Seiber's website for USB letters to a set range, eg E, F, G, H.

The program has been updated to work with vista as well, so you can have vista on a letter other than c:

It gives a screen: down on the lower right, "select default windows path"  = WINDOWS  "mount install-drive as"  C:\   If you change this to S: and FENSTER then install windows into partition 3, then you get the %systemroot%= S:\FENSTER.   I mean, how hard can a gui be?

What it actually does is hack the install tapes.  You roll a cdrom from this, and install it from that.  You can set other questions as well.

Comment: I wait some minutes for another answer. If dont have better answer, I accept it.

Comment: @Janci-Panci Did it work? If it worked, go ahead and accept it; if it didn't work, don't accept it because it will just confuse future readers.

Comment: I will try it .

Comment: This answer seems incomplete.  It does not actually explain how to do this.